# Обработка текста. Удаление дубликатов

Tags: c#

Поставлена задача, удалить дубликаты слов(не учитывая регистр,Мама и мама одинаковое слово) двух рассказов. Проблема заключается в том что некоторые слова он не удаляет.Например те, где первое стоит в конце продолжения а, дубликат в начале.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 namespace WordCount
{
    class Program
    {


        public static void EditorText(string a)
        {
            var newText = Regex.Replace(a, "[\"-.?!)(,:]", "");
            newText = string.Join(" ", newText.Split(' ').Distinct());
            using (var sw = File.AppendText(@"\p.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(newText);
            }
        }
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"test\o.txt", Encoding.Default);
            var test = sr.ReadToEnd();
            StreamReader se = new StreamReader(@"\test\t.txt", Encoding.Default);
            var test2 = se.ReadToEnd();
            var test3 = test + test2;
            EditorText(test3);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам в конце нужно получить новый текст без совпадений?

Comment: Да, чтобы в 3 файле  были уникальные слова из двух рассказов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти таким путем:

Допустим есть файлы `1.txt`, `2.txt` и `3.txt`. В будущем к примеру могут добавиться еще, значит мы можем сразу написать метод, который будет принимать массив файлов и их обрабатывать.

**Создадим этот метод:**
На вход он пусть принимает массив, а выходом будет одна строка со всеми уникальными словами.

```
public static string Check(params string[] files)
{
    var text = files.Where(File.Exists)
        .SelectMany(x => File.ReadAllText(x).Split())
        .Select(x => new string(x.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()))
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    return string.Join(" ", text);
}
```

Поясню что тут и как:

- `files.Where(File.Exists)` - файлы, которые отсутствуют нам не подходят, поэтому мы смело берем только те, которые существую на диске.
- `.SelectMany(x => File.ReadAllText(x).Split())` - Читаем каждый файл и разбиваем текст по пробелу (заметьте, не обязательно ставить символ для разбития, если нам необходимо разбить по пробелу. Метод Split это делает по умолчанию!). На этом этапе у нас будет массив слов всех файлов.
- `.Select(x => new string(x.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()))` - Удаляем все лишние символы (кроме цифр и букв).
- `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))` - чистим все от пустых строк (если есть).
- `.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);` - Сверяем все слова и убираем те, что повторяются (`CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` здесь именно игнорирование регистра).
- `return string.Join(" ", text);` - собираем строку из массива, разбивая слова пробелом и возвращаем ее.

**Вызываем полученный метод:**
Здесь мы вызываем наш метод `Check`, которому передаем все необходимые файлы для сравнения и результат выводим для примера в консоль.

```
Console.WriteLine(Check("1.txt","2.txt","3.txt"));
```

Для примера давайте заполним три файла некими данными:

1. > 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
2. > 1 2 7 9 12 63 84 3 78 677
3. > абв вба 1сс, qw/!2g - прр2

Запускаем и смотрим на результат:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 12 63 84 78 677 абв вба 1сс qw2g прр2

Все значения у нас уникальны и текст подчищен (можно сравнить `qw/!2g` с результатом).
Удачи в изучении C#!

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, с моим примером сработало. Нужны будут правки, напишите в комментарии. Вот код:

```
 string [] text1 = "Много котов собак и птичек во дворе".Split(' ');
        string [] text2 = "Не много котов собак и попугаев в доме".Split(' ');
        HashSet<string> vs = new HashSet<string>();
        var a = text1.Concat(text2);
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            vs.Add(item.ToLower());
        }
        foreach (var item in vs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
//Вывод:

//много
//котов
//собак
//и
//птичек
//во
//дворе
//не
//попугаев
//в
//доме
```

Comment: Вам определенно надо ознакомиться с расширяющими методами `Concat()` и `ToDictionary()` или хотя бы с типом данных `HashSet`. Тот код, что вы написали, он очень неэффективен в плане производительности.

Comment: Да, я ознакомлен с методом `Concat()`, который соединяет две последовательности. Но с одной целой никак не смог определить как удалить тот нужный элемент.

Comment: Я поэтому вам и написал. Обратите внимание на время работы вашего алгоритма, почитайте что нибудь по структурам данных, это очень вам поможет в профессии, если будете работать программистом, и убережет от неэффективного кода.

Comment: @tym32167 вот так лучше? Хорошо когда кто-то правит. Можно совершенствоваться. С таким интересом бороздил по интернету что бы узнать "как можно сделать лучше?"

Comment: В вашем случае достаточно будет `foreach (var item in text1.Concat(text2).Distinct())`, ну, или то, что вы написали - оно по скорости работы примерно одинаковое.